# Rate limiting by count per minute with httr

Tags: r, api, httr

I'm working with the Discogs API, trying to extract community information (haves and wants, lowest price etc) for my collection.

Unfortunately, it has a rate limit of 25 per minute and I can't work out a way to work that limit into my current code (see below).
I could use sys.sleep(), but I'm not sure where that would go within the code.

```
communityData <- lapply(as.list(collection$release_id), function(obj){
  url <- httr::GET(paste0("https://api.discogs.com/releases/", obj))
  url <- rjson::fromJSON(rawToChar(url$content))
  data.frame(release_id = obj, 
             label = url$label[[1]]$name %||% NA,
             year = url$year %||% NA, 
             title = url$title %||% NA, 
             artist_name = url$artist[[1]]$name %||% NA, 
             styles = url$styles[[1]] %||% NA,
             genre = url$genre[[1]] %||% NA,
             average_note = url$community$rating$average %||% NA, 
             votes = url$community$rating$count %||% NA, 
             want = url$community$want %||% NA, 
             have = url$community$have %||% NA, 
             lowest_price = url$lowest_price %||% NA, 
             country = url$country %||% NA)
}) %>% do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  unique()
```

Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine to just insert the sleep command directly before you return your value. This will give you a pattern of query the url, extract information, sleep, return value, repeat. Aka, edit the above code chunk like so:

```r
communityData <- lapply(as.list(collection$release_id), function(obj){
  url <- httr::GET(paste0("https://api.discogs.com/releases/", obj))
  url <- rjson::fromJSON(rawToChar(url$content))

  # 1 minute for 25 requests -- ~ 2.4 seconds of sleep between each request
  Sys.sleep(2.4)
  
  data.frame(release_id = obj, 
             label = url$label[[1]]$name %||% NA,
             year = url$year %||% NA, 
             title = url$title %||% NA, 
             artist_name = url$artist[[1]]$name %||% NA, 
             styles = url$styles[[1]] %||% NA,
             genre = url$genre[[1]] %||% NA,
             average_note = url$community$rating$average %||% NA, 
             votes = url$community$rating$count %||% NA, 
             want = url$community$want %||% NA, 
             have = url$community$have %||% NA, 
             lowest_price = url$lowest_price %||% NA, 
             country = url$country %||% NA)
}) %>% do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  unique()
```